# Deleting specific files ending with specific strings in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to delete specific folders in a sub-directory. For example, I have a directory where output of a specific result from something else collects, like:

```
Jobs/Market/Java
```

In that directory, I'll have outputs like these with dates and some random numbers in the end:

```
OUTPUT_201908809_134243
OUTPUT_201908810_242323
OUTPUT_201908811_152342
OUTPUT_201908815_124243
```

I'm trying to run a job that deletes folders that have '201908809'-'201908811' and leaves the remaining ones.

I've tried to manually deleting them using rm -r and the folder name. I know there has to be an easier way. I've looked up some things on stack and found lines that only delete folders that have an starting or and ending of the folder name.

What's the standard way of accomplishing this with Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards for rm for example in this case you can use `rm -rf *_201908809_*`  * means match all characters

https://www.shell-tips.com/2006/11/04/using-bash-wildcards/